# How to skip "Checked available update data for" all modules when I just want to update core or a specific module?

Tags: drush, upgrading, security

I'm upgrading a lot of my Drupal sites to 7.32. Unfortunately it takes a lot of time for each site because of some update check that I don't need.

On [How to upgrade only core with drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133796/how-to-upgrade-only-core-with-drush/133797#133797) I learned I can use `drush up drupal` to only upgrade core. But unfortunately `drush` is still checking a lot of statuses, which takes a long time for every site:

```
Checking available update data ...
Checked available update data for Administration menu.                                                                                                                                                                         
Checked available update data for Admin VBO Views.                                                                                                                                                                                 
Checked available update data for Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation.                                                                                                                                                                     
Checked available update data for Block.
...
```

How can I skip this? I just want drush to fetch 7.32, check if the site is still functional and head to the next site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drush calls Drupal code to update the list of available releases, so regrettably there is no way to update the release info for just some subset of available projects.